# converting JSON data into javascript Object format

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, javascript-objects

My API is returning data into the below format.

```
{
    "name": "Mahima",
    "surname": "Saxena",
}
```

I need to convert the same into below format.

```
{
    name: "Mahima",
    surname: "Saxena",
}
```

I need to remove double quote(`" "`) from `key` . how can I do this?

I tried below code.

```
var abc = {
  "name": "Mahima",
  "surname": "Saxena",
};
console.log(abc);
console.log(JSON.parse(abc));
```

I am getting `error` in code.

[image]

what mistake I am doing?

Comment: In your example, `abc` is already a js object (and not a JSON string). Is this on purpose?

Comment: You cannot parse a JS object - it's not a string - so JS tries to coerce the JS object in to a string resulting in `[object Object]` which is of course not valid JSON

Comment: So the API is returning JSON. That's a very standard data format. And you want to transform it into something that … isn't JSON. Why? (And your code example uses a JS object literal, not JSON too).

Comment: In addition to the other comments:
If you have an API call from the client side to the server side, you will need to use json.parse in order to convert the returned data to js object.

Comment: the error is from this line `console.log(JSON.parse(abc));`, your parsing an *already* object. JSON contains double-quotes for properties and shouldn't cause any issues or need removing, the issue with your JSON is you have a trailing `,` after `"surname": "Saxena",` which is invalid JSON which is why its actually not working. Fix your API to not add the trailing `,` (by not building the JSON yourself but instead using `res.json()`)

Comment: Please post the code that actually retrieves the data. `abc` is already an object. How did you get it? In real code, getting a response and parsing it would be eg `const response= await fetch(someUrl); const abcObject=await response.json();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the concept of "json string". It is easy as it looks like how javascript typically shows the contents of an object. I have stumbled on this myself.

See

```
JSON.parse(abc)
```

The method 'parse' takes an argument that must be a string.
It then returns an object.

You already have an object in `abc` with

```
var abc = {
  "name": "Mahima",
  "surname": "Saxena",
};
```

So there is no need to convert anything.

The formats

```
{
    "name": "Mahima",
    "surname": "Saxena",
}
```

and

```
{
    name: "Mahima",
    surname: "Saxena",
}
```

are the same. They are 1 object with the properties `name` and `surname`.